# Dual monitors don't work on Elitebook 8570p

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hp-elitebook

I just got my shiny new HP EliteBook 8570p and although the documentation and what I've read online indicates two or three monitors can be used simultaneously, I'm unable to.  I've got the laptop display running, and just one other display. Screen Resolution window shows it's detected the other monitor, but when I try to extend to it I get the error message, "The display settings could not be saved.  Please try a different combination of display settings." Any got a solution? I'm running Win8.

Comment: You sure the documentation is for that exact laptop. 3 monitors in laptops usually require intel ivy-bridge. And documentations usually cover atleast 3 different models.

Answer (score 2):

Here are your options for multiple screens with the Elitebook 8570P as well as most computers with a DisplayPort interface.

If you plug in 2 screens such as 1-VGA and 1-digital then they will both work but you lose your monitor. If you want your monitor plus one additional screen you can choose either option. However, if you want to run 2 or 3 screens and keep your monitor then you have to go through the "DisplayPort" for all external monitors and you get two options.

1. You can get 3 monitors that have 'DisplayPort in' *and* DisplayPort out' interfaces. Plug one into the computer, the second into the first and the third into the second. This is called "daisy-chaining" and your DP will run all 3, but these monitors maybe be hard to find and/or expensive.
2. Buy a DisplayPort splitter. Plug it into your computer's DP and the plug your monitors into the splitter. Voilà, like magic. This is the way to go.

Another user mentioned being able to use more monitors via advanced docking options. I have seen some models that will let you use 2 external monitors while using your laptop screen by using a docking station however for the investment made I would recommend the DP splitter that lets you use an additional 3 externals.

Just make sure when researching, ordering and buying that you get the type of output on your splitter to match the cables and monitors you have or will get.

I use my Elitebook 8570P with a 4-way DisplayPort splitter and have used 2 Dell S2340M 24" monitors and a third 31" I borrowed from a friend and still had use of my laptop screen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - do you have the AMD discrete graphics in?
This supports up to four external screens. 3 via advanced docking plus one at the DP of the machine itself.

But HP is fooling here!
I'm figthing the same fight right now.

Laptop Screen, DVI and VGA count as legacy devices. Two of them are allowed.
For more you need Display port connections.
And Yes, there are cheap Display Port to DVI adapters available - they will not work!
You need to purchase Active adapters which costs a fortune.

Comment: My DP to DVI adapter says "active", yet it isn't working...